# PHP and mysql booking with error "Unsupported operand types"

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on room booking where i succeeded to get the number of rooms booked on particular dates. I'm having trouble subtracting the number of rooms already booked from the total rooms. It keeps telling me that the '$No_of_Rooms' is an array and i'm not able to subtract it from the total rooms. I have this error "Fatal error: Unsupported operand types...".

```
//getting the number of rooms already booked on particular dates
$query = "SELECT count(*)
    FROM reservation
    WHERE (RoomID = '$ID' AND (Arrival <= '$check_out' AND Departure >= '$check_in'))";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if($result){
    $No_of_Rooms = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $FreeRooms = $Total_Rooms - $No_of_Rooms; //-->error redirected here
    var_dump($No_of_Rooms);
    var_dump($FreeRooms);
}
```

Can someone guide me on this, i've just started learning php. I've looked at many threads with this type of error but still nothing resembling mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$No_of_Rooms` *is* an array: an associative array, with named keys corresponding to column names. See the PHP docs on [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php). You'll have to extract the number of rooms from that array, and then you can do operations on it.

Please note, `mysql_fetch_assoc` has been deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 in favor of other extensions like [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Thank you for replying. I've been looking around and i wonder if i could use " $No_of_Rooms = mysql_result($result, 0, "count"); " instead of " $No_of_Rooms = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ; " to get a value?